# Exchange Appointment Types

Tags: web-services, exchange-server, ews-managed-api

I use the following code to save an appointment via Exchange Web Services Managed API:

```
Appointment appointment = new Appointment(m_exchangeService);
appointment.Subject = subject;
appointment.Body = body;
appointment.Start = start;
appointment.End = end;
appointment.Save();
```

When I do this the Appointment is created as a 'meeting' in Outlook. But I just want to have it as normal Appointment not a meeting.
How do i do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found an answer. The following code creates a normal nonmeeting Appointment

```
appointment.Save(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, SendInvitationsMode.SendToNone);
```