# Updating an Appointment causes it to change to a Meeting in EWS 1.1

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices

Here's what I'm trying to do:

- get all items on a user's calendar between two dates
- update the `Location` or `Subject` for some items

I get the items with:

`FindItemsResults<Appointment> findResults = calendar.FindAppointments(new CalendarView(startDate, endDate));`

This query works fine. But whenever I call Update to save the item I get an exception:

`Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceResponseException: One or more recipients are invalid.`

Even though I get an exception, the item is saved and gets changed to have `IsMeeting` set to true!  Now the updated item is a meeting with an organizer etc...  This is, effectively, data corruption for me.

Here's the code. It is no more complicated than this.  I've tested it by just changing `Location` or `Subject` and both cause the problem.

```
Appointment a = Appointment.Bind(_service, new ItemId(id));
a.Location = newLocation
a.Update(ConflictResolutionMode.AlwaysOverwrite);
```

Am I missing some concept or something? This seems like a pretty egregious problem.

FWIW, this is EWS 1.1 against an Office 365 server.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I figured it out with help from this Question:

[Exchange Appointment Types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3870818/exchange-appointment-types)

The key is the `Update` method needs to be called with the `SendInvitationsOrCancellationsMode.SendToNone` flag set in the 2nd parameter.

Like this:

```
a.Update(ConflictResolutionMode.AlwaysOverwrite, SendInvitationsOrCancellationsMode.SendToNone);
```

Comment: This solution worked for us as well tig.  I don't understand why a meeting with no attendees would throw this exception, however your solution worked.  Thanks!

Comment: I've given a more complete answer that explains why you're getting the error and how you can do an update that will send updates to the attendees rather than never sending an update as this solution suggests.

Answer (score 5):

So tig's answer works when you never want to send out appointment updates to the other attendees. However to answer this properly you actually need to get the attendee state loaded.

By default it is trying to send appointment updates to the attendees, however your appointment object doesn't have the attendee state loaded and is hence blowing up. When you do the bind you should load the attendee properties. You should probably also load the organizer as well to cover another edge case:

- AppointmentSchema.RequiredAttendees
- AppointmentSchema.OptionalAttendees
- AppointmentSchema.Resources
- AppointmentSchema.Organizer

This will get the attendees populated if you want to do an update that sends out updates to the attendees.

However there is then another edge case that you have to worry about. If you have an appointment with no attendees added to it (just the organizer), then EWS may still complain and throw this error. It will actually work for appointments in some states, but fail in other states.

So the most complete solution is a combination of:

1. Loading the attendee state.
2. Inspecting the attendee state to see if there are any attendees other than the organizer (depending on how the appointment was created the organizer may or may not appear in the RequiredAttendees collection). If there are not then you must use SendInvitationsOrCancellationsMode.SendToNone.

So the full sample would look something like:

```
Appointment a = Appointment.Bind(_service, new ItemId(id), new PropertySet(AppointmentSchema.RequiredAttendees, AppointmentSchema.OptionalAttendees, AppointmentSchema.Resources, AppointmentSchema.Organizer));
a.Location = newLocation

// Check if the appointment has attendees other than the organizer. The organizer may
// or may not appear in the required attendees list.
if (HasNoOtherAttendee(a.Organizer.Address, a.RequiredAttendees) &&
    (a.OptionalAttendees.Count == 0) && (a.Resources.Count == 0))
{
    a.Update(ConflictResolutionMode.AlwaysOverwrite, SendInvitationsOrCancellationsMode.SendToNone);
}
else
{
    // We have other attendees in the appointment, so we can use SendToAllAndSaveCopy so
    // they will see the update.
    a.Update(ConflictResolutionMode.AlwaysOverwrite, SendInvitationsOrCancellationsMode.SendToAllAndSaveCopy);
}


bool HasNoOtherAttendee(string email, AttendeeCollection attendees)
{
    bool emptyOrOnlyMe = true;
    foreach (var a in attendees)
    {
        if (!string.Equals(email, a.Address, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            emptyOrOnlyMe = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return emptyOrOnlyMe;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer this bit of the question

> "Even though I get an exception, the item is saved and gets changed to
>   have IsMeeting set to true! Now the updated item is a meeting with an
>   organizer etc... This is, effectively, data corruption for me."

The Microsoft documentation states, in the small print,  "*A meeting request is just an appointment that has attendees. You can convert an appointment into a meeting request by adding required attendees, optional attendees, or resources to the appointment*"  - as seen here
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd633641%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx

In other words, as soon as you have **any** attendees, Exchange converts it to a meeting automatically.

Comment: The other direction doesn't hold, by the way. If you take a meeting in EWS and remove all attendees, it is NOT converted back into an appointment.

Answer (score -1):

```
public static bool UpdateAppointment(ExchangeCredential credentials,
           ItemId appointmentId, string newLocation, string newSubject, 
DateTime startTime,
            DateTime endTime)
        {
            ExchangeService service = GetExchangeService(credentials);
            try
            {
                Appointment appt = Appointment.Bind(service, appointmentId,
                    new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly, AppointmentSchema.Start,
                        AppointmentSchema.ReminderDueBy, AppointmentSchema.End,   AppointmentSchema.StartTimeZone,
                        AppointmentSchema.TimeZone));

                appt.Location = newLocation;
                appt.Start = startTime;
                appt.End = endTime;
                appt.Subject = newSubject;
                // very important! you must load the new timeZone
                appt.StartTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.Local;
                //appt.Body.Text = newBody; //if needed
                appt.Update(ConflictResolutionMode.AlwaysOverwrite);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }

            return true;
        }
```